# Perforce : Copying files with Certain Label

Tags: version-control, perforce

I need to copy files with Certain label from perforce and put it on some "Non workspace" folder lets say c:\Temp

When i do p4 sync @LABEL labelled files get copied to workspace but i want to pick up those files and dump it somewhere else.

I tried exploring few different options like p4 copy but i dont think they will serve the purpose.

Prob i can Delete all the files in workspace and then do

p4 sync @LABEL and that will give me exactly those files that are labelled but i think there could be better solution ...

Thanks

Comment: Sync'ing the files and then zipping them up yourself seems like a fine solution to me. Usually, I use a separate workspace for this, not the workspace I'm using for my regular tasks. If you use a separate workspace, you can run 'sync -p' and/or delete the workspace when you're done, to avoid the extra book keeping on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Windows. If you do this regularly, I'd recommend creating a simplce .bat file to do this process for you. The script below would clean out the workspace, sync only the files in the label, then copy them to your C:\Temp directory. If the label would be changing, you might consider doing something similar as a Custom Tool.

```
p4 sync //...@0
p4 sync //...@mytestlabel,@mytestlabel
set TARGET=C:\Temp\MyFiles
copy C:\MyFiles %TARGET%
```

Comment: Alternatively you can replace the first two lines with just "p4 sync @mytestlabel", which will remove all files that aren't in the label.